# tom cat closes just after a second I click on startup.bat

Tags: tomcat

when I click on the tomcat server , It opens and it closes. Can anyone mention the reason for this and how can I correct it.

Comment: click on it where? What's opening and closing?

Answer (score 3):

check the logs under logs/catalina.out

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the mention of `startup.bat` you're obviously running windows.

Tomcat's startup routines typically start another process, that will get its own console window once it's running. So, apart from the missing separate console window you're experiencing exactly the way it works by design.

However, as the separate console window (with tomcat log output) is missing (I'm guessing this: You're not mentioning it explicitly, but wouldn't ask if this was there, right?) some error condition must keep it from starting. This can be "no java" or anything else.

How can you find it? Well, when you double-click a batch file, it will open a command prompt (console) window for the time that the batch file executes. As tomcat might write some error message to this window, it doesn't help if it disappears immediately after printing the error message.

Open a command prompt (Windows-R, type `cmd.exe`) and `cd` into the directory that your startup.bat is located. There you execute `startup.bat` by just typing its name. Once the batch file finishes execution you're back in the command prompt but will still be able to see the error message. Whatever it tells you, that's what you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tomcat root folder and check for catalina in logs folder. It will show the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).